# How can I specify which submit action is the default?

Tags: 8, forms

I have a custom form, with two different submit actions. Here's my code (edited for brevity):

```
class EditSlideshow extends FormBase
{
    
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        
        $form['actions']['delete'] = [
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Delete Slideshow'),
            '#submit' => ['::submitDelete'],
            '#validate' => ['::validateDelete'],
            '#attributes' => ['class' => ['btn', 'btn-blue']],
        ];
        
        $form['actions']['submit'] = [
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Save Changes'),
            '#submit' => ['::submitForm'],
            '#validate' => ['::validateForm'],
            '#attributes' => ['class' => ['btn', 'btn-blue']],
        ];
        
    }
    
}
```

This mostly works: if I submit the form by clicking on the "Save Changes" button, then `validateForm()` and `submitForm()` get called; and if I submit the form by clicking on the "Delete Slideshow" button, then `validateDelete()` and `submitDelete()` get called.

But if I submit the form via some *other* means – for example, by pressing the Enter key while the cursor is inside a text field – then the *first* action gets called (in this case, the `delete` action).

That isn't what I want – the `submit` action should be the default, not `delete`.

Is there some way that I can tell Drupal to treat `submit` as the default action instead?

A few things come to mind:

1. I could register the `submit` action before the `delete` action, so that *it* becomes the first (and therefore the default). I'd rather not do this, though – I want the "Save Changes" button to appear after the "Delete Slideshow" button.
2. To get around *that*, I could use CSS to rearrange the buttons. This seems kind of hackish, though.
3. Instead of implementing "Delete Slideshow" as an action, I could render it as `<input type="button">` inside a `#markup` item, and add some custom JavaScript to detect and handle clicks on this button. However, this means that I'd no longer be able to use `FormBase`'s built-in submit handling to process this "action" – I guess I would need to create my own separate route, controller, etc. (The details are somewhat beyond my understanding of Drupal.)

Any suggestions? (Bonus points if you can show me how to add a confirmation popup to the `delete` action.) Thanks!

Comment: Is this just a matter of setting #weight?

Comment: OR move the submit code above delete.

Comment: Your bonus points comment sounds like a great new question, unless there's already a question with an answer on here.

Comment: This is actually determined by [the HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#implicit-submission): _A <form> element’s default button is the first Submit Button in tree order whose form owner is that form element._. With that in mind, CSS seems like the right choice for what you need